# Sorting fetched collection from ActiveRecord or ThinkingSphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, thinking-sphinx

I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to sort collection from ActiveRecord or Thinking Sphinx without re-select everything from database/sphinx?
   ie.

   `@models = Model.where("foo = :foo", {:foo => params[:foo]})`
   `models.some_code_or_method_which_will_resort_everything`
2. Is this game worth a candle(sorting array/collection without fetching again)? I wonder which option is better for performance.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

So, this game is worth a candle when you:

- don't use pagination(you must have all records)
- refresh page div with ajax(don't fetch everything again with calling index or show action)

Art for art's sake..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty much sure 'sort' should work:

```
  @models.sort! { |a,b| a.foo <=> b.foo }
```

Answering the second question, yes, it does. It pretty much depends on the amount of objects in your collection, but generally it is usually a performance win

Comment: Can you not sort as part of the database/Sphinx call? That way, the DB/Sphinx does all the hard work for you (and is likely faster than your Ruby code). It also means that paginated search results will be sorted _then_ paginated.

Comment: initially, db will sort faster. But in case you need the same dataset but ordered differently - you'll need one more query, which is both db and ruby orm. This is definitely slower than just a ruby sort